# 500 Internal Server Error Wordpress htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, internal-server-error

My wordpress site says "500 Internal Server Error" after I modify my url site in wordpress setting. Then I google to fix that problem. They suggest to rename my htaccess file in wp file manager and my website load after that but it became a plain html only.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to access the database, change the value of the `option_value` column in the `siteurl` & `home` rows in the `wp_options` table.

Set them to be the url which you used previously, before crashing the site by changing the urls on the settings-page in wp-admin.

Here's a graphic for your reference
[image]